Issue Connecting IntelliJ to Wildfly in Docker via Management Port
Title:
Unable to connect IntelliJ to Wildfly in Docker via Management Port
Description:
I have a Wildfly server (version 26.1.3.Final) running in a Docker container with the following port mappings:
0.0.0.0:18080->8080/tcp
0.0.0.0:18787->8787/tcp
0.0.0.0:19990->9990/tcp

The management port of the Wildfly server is accessible via jboss-cli.sh and in the browser at http://localhost:19990/.
However, when I try to run the configuration in IntelliJ to deploy and start the Wildfly server, I get the following error:
Unable to connect to localhost:19990, reason:  com.intellij.javaee.process.common.WrappedException:  java.io.IOException: java.net.ConnectException:  WFLYPRT0053: Could not connect to remote+http://localhost:19990.  The connection failed.

The credentials are correct.
The management port (19990) is configured correctly.
The version of the local Wildfly installation (26.1.3) matches the version of the Wildfly server in the Docker container.

Question:
Why can't IntelliJ connect to the management port of the Wildfly server in the Docker container, even though it is accessible through jboss-cli.sh and the browser? Are there any additional configurations needed to establish the connection properly?
